Is there a way to see data in a KV store from Vercel dashboard?
Is there a way to see data in a KV store from Vercel dashboard?
I created an application from a template that uses the Vercel KV store. How do I see what is in the store? Can I do it from the Vercel dashboard. Do I need to download a client?

This is one way.

// When storing the entire array in Vercel KV
await kv.set('spaceships', dataValues.array);
console.log('Initial data', await kv.get('spaceships'));

